# Is it possible to launch the spacecraft after 2050?

Tags: civilization-5

I wasn't able to add the engine part (i.e. my last part) of my space shuttle at the end of game... Was it because the game already over (>2050) ?

PS/ I succeed to add all other parts. For the last one, the "Add to spaceship" wasn't there at all...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once a civilization has achieved a victory in a game, it's no longer possible to launch the spaceship and win by a science victory.

In 2050 the civilization with the most points wins the game, although it is possible to continue playing after that you cannot win in another way anymore. If you want to prevent this from happening you can disable the time victory in the game's settings when starting a new game.